# In C - function get char pointer and add characters to it

Tags: c, char

I am trying to think how to write a function that get char* and return a pointer to the same char but after added to his end few constant characters.

```
char* addExtension(char* FileName)
{

}
```

Comment: +1 for the sense of humor @H2CO3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just what the standard library function [`strcat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) (for "string concatenate") does, I think. You should look into using it.

Also beware of the dangers of buffer overrun, a function such as this (and `strcat()`, for that matter) is inherently unsafe since it doesn't include information about available space.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't do that, not with arbitrary strings anyway.
Strings can be:

- Constants (like the literal "hello world"). Those can't be modified
- Char arrays (like char thingie[10]). They have fixed amout of space - if you
  run out of it, you get the very friendly `Segmentation fault` or worse.
- `malloc`'d pointers - they have fixed amount of space, too, and need to be `free`d.

You can copy the string and return a new one, but that can result in memory leaks
if you don't take care of the old one. Example

```
char *copycat(char *first, char *second) {
    char *result = malloc(strlen(first)+strlen(second)+1);
    strcpy(result, first);
    strcpy(result+strlen(first), second);
    return result;
}
```